# The word for "not well described by statistics"

Tags: single-word-requests

I used to know this 25-cent word, and I have forgotten it. It describes a phenomenon where common descriptive statistics like mean and variance misrepresent the individuals or maybe the phenomenon itself. (I don't know because I can't look it up!) I believe it begins with an e, probably an en- or eu-. Does it sound familiar to anyone?

"Children's classroom learning should not be reduced to test scores, because  learning is  -------- "

Comment: Requests for a single word are best accompanied by a sample sentence in which the desired word might appear as a blank.

Comment: Enthetic, eustatic, endocastic, something like that. Not ecological, not epistemic, not endogenous.

Comment: *Enigmatic* might just work here, but it's a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about outliers, or potentially the results of any dataset with outliers?

If you have a set of restaurant ratings:

```
1, 4.5,4.5,5
```

The mean is skewed significantly by the outlier of 1 (mean =3.75) and a mean of 3.75 also does not represent the outlier, 1, well.

Comment: Not exactly.  Conceptually similar but more descriptive of the whole collection or phenomenon.  Income is ________ because of the skewing at both the low and high ends of the range.

Comment: Variant? As in talking about how large the spread of data is?

Comment: My example here turned out to be inapt.

Answer (score 1):

Phenomena that *can't* be well described by statistics are generally referred to as being statistically "intractable" meaning you can't get a handle on them that way.

Comment: Ok, that is roughly the meaning I want.  Now can you think of the technical term, possibly from social science, that begins with an "e"?

Comment: @JKelly Sorry not off the top of my head no. I'll keep thinking and get back to you.

Comment: I am only being picky because I want to chase down related materials with google. Thanks!

Comment: @JKelly You can have a data set that yields "enigmatic results", results that don't convey what you expect given the general shape of the raw data field.

Answer (score 1):

entropic

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entropic#Adjective):

> Of, pertaining to, or as a consequence of entropy.

*Entropy* from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entropy):

> (statistics, information theory, countable) A measure of the amount of information and noise present in a signal.
>
> The tendency of a system that is left to itself to descend into chaos.

You might also want to read the related Q&A on [stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194253/what-does-entropy-tell-us).

Comment: Thanks, you sent me looking down the right (physics) path!

Answer (score 0):

The word was "ergodic" -- "the ensemble average equals the time average" -- and the concept I was trying to research was "nonergodic." The meaning is a little different than I'd recalled.  It's more like a phenomenon that's reliant on its history, but I couldn't discover that without the actual term.  Thanks to all!